# Table: Vertical spacing on a line with text wrapping. How to vertically center the content of a cell belonging to this row?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, center

I'm making a task scheduling table. I divided the table into 16 rows and 12 columns. In the first two columns, I describe the activities: I reserved the first column for the dash to “simulate” the itemization environment. In columns 3 to 12 I have distributed the months in which I intend to carry out the activities. It happens that in some activities the text that describes them is very long and when it reaches the edge of the cell the text is broken, increasing the height of the line. As a result, when I want to associate an activity with a month where I intend to carry it out, I have not been able to vertically center the marker, in this case, the X. I have already consulted several manuals; I tried several things, but I was unsuccessful. I decided to ask here how to vertically center the X marker. I hope you can help me.

**Detail**: I only want to center the text in cells in rows 3 to 16 and in columns 3 to 12.

Below I provide a minimum code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}  % Pacote necessário para ajustar a altura das células

% Definir margens
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  % Ajusta a altura das células
        \newcolumntype{V}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1} }
        %\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c >{\hsize=16\hsize}X *{12}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.32\hsize}V{0.08\linewidth} }}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\MakeTextUppercase{Atividades}}} & \textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Set/2023}} & \textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Out/2023}} & \textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Nov/2023}} & \textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Dez/2023}} & \textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Jan/2024}} & \textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Fev/2024}} & \textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Mar/2024}} & \textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Abr/2024}} & \textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Ma/2024}} & \textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Jun/2024}} \\
            \midrule
            -- & Levantamento bibliográfico                & X & X & & & & & & & &  \\
            -- & Elaboração do projeto de TCC              & X & X & & & & & & & &  \\
            -- & Apresentação do projeto de TCC            &   & X & & & & & & & &  \\
            -- & Luz como onda eletromagnética transversal &   & X & & & & & & & &  \\
            -- & Relação de dispersão                      & & & X& & & & &  & &  \\
            -- & Ondas transversais são descritas também pelos graus de polarização - revisão                                      &   &   & X & & & & & & &  \\
            -- & Tipos de polarização - revisão          &   &   &   & X & & & & & &  \\
            -- & Polarizadores lineares                  &   &   &   & X &  & & & & &  \\
            -- & Polarizadores por defasagem (1/4 de onda) & &   &   &   & X&  & & & &  \\
            -- & Elementos de propagação de ondas EM em dielétricos anisotrópicos -- cristais anisotrópicos                                &   &   &   &   & & X &  & & &  \\
            -- & Birrefringência em cristais anisotrópicos & & & & & & & X &  &  &  \\
            -- & Estudo dos efeitos da birrefringência em polarizados de 1/4 de onda & & & & & & & & X &  &   \\
            -- & Produção e publicação de uma artigo em uma revista de ensino da física &  & X & X & X & X & X & X & X &  &   \\
            -- & Redação do TCC  &  & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X &   \\
            -- & Entrega do TCC a banca &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X &   \\
            -- & Defesa do TCC &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Answer (score 2):

I'd get rid of the first column (with the dashes) and apply the `X` column type exclusively to the text column; I'd use a simple `c` column type for the the ten data columns.

The instruction `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` assures that each row with "X"es is centered vertically relative to the row(s) of the legend on its left.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or 'brazilian'?
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,graphicx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage{geometry}
% Definir margens
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm}

%\usepackage{array}  % 'array' is loaded automatically by 'tabularx'

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  % Ajusta a altura das células
% \centering % <-- no need for this here
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}X *{10}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{\MakeTextUppercase{Atividades}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Set/2023}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Out/2023}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Nov/2023}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Dez/2023}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Jan/2024}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Fev/2024}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Mar/2024}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Abr/2024}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Ma/2024}}  & 
\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Jun/2024}} \\
\midrule
Levantamento bibliográfico
     & $\times$ & $\times$  \\
Elaboração do projeto de TCC    
     & $\times$ & $\times$  \\
Apresentação do projeto de TCC  
     & & $\times$  \\
Luz como onda eletromagnética transversal 
     & & $\times$  \\
Relação de dispersão            
     & & & $\times$  \\
Ondas transversais são descritas também pelos graus de polarização~-- revisão 
     & & & $\times$  \\
Tipos de polarização~-- revisão          
     & & & & $\times$  \\
Polarizadores lineares        
     & & & & $\times$  \\
Polarizadores por defasagem (1/4 de onda) 
     & & & & & $\times$ \\
Elementos de propagação de ondas EM em dielétricos anisotrópicos~-- cristais anisotrópicos            
     & & & & & & $\times$  \\
Birrefringência em cristais anisotrópicos 
     & & & & & & & $\times$ & & & \\
Estudo dos efeitos da birrefringência em polarizados de 1/4 de onda 
     & & & & & & & & $\times$ & & \\
Produção e publicação de uma artigo em uma revista de ensino da física 
     & & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & & \\
Redação do TCC  
     & & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & \\
Entrega do TCC a banca 
     & & & & & & & & & $\times$ & \\
Defesa do TCC 
     & & & & & & & & & & $\times$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}

\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{\qquad} >{\leavevmode\llap{--\enskip}}X[l,m] *{10}{c}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ATIVIDADES}}  % \multicolumn to delete the dash
    & \RowStyle{\bfseries\rotate} 
      Set/2023 & Out/2023 & Nov/2023 & Dez/2023 & Jan/2024 & Fev/2024 
      & Mar/2024 & Abr/2024 & Ma/2024 & Jun/2024\\
    \midrule
    Levantamento bibliográfico               &X&X& & & & & & & & \\
    Elaboração do projeto de TCC             &X&X& & & & & & & & \\
    Apresentação do projeto de TCC           & &X& & & & & & & & \\
    Luz como onda eletromagnética transversal& &X& & & & & & & & \\
    Relação de dispersão                     & & &X& & & & & & & \\
    Ondas transversais são descritas também 
    pelos graus de polarização - revisão     & & &X& & & & & & & \\
    Tipos de polarização - revisão           & & & &X& & & & & & \\
    Polarizadores lineares                   & & & &X& & & & & & \\
    Polarizadores por defasagem (1/4 de onda)& & & & &X& & & & & \\
    Elementos de propagação de ondas EM em 
    dielétricos anisotrópicos -- cristais 
    anisotrópicos                            & & & & & &X& & & & \\
    Birrefringência em cristais anisotrópicos& & & & & & &X& & & \\
    Estudo dos efeitos da birrefringência em 
    polarizados de 1/4 de onda               & & & & & & & &X& & \\
    Produção e publicação de uma artigo em 
    uma revista de ensino da física          & &X&X&X&X&X&X&X& & \\
    Redação do TCC                           & &X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X& \\
    Entrega do TCC a banca                   & & & & & & & & &X& \\
    Defesa do TCC                            & & & & & & & & & &X\\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]